# reporting server error in IE browser

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Using server server 2008 r2 and vs08 i use SQL reporting services and i also install iis so when i deploy reports it show me like this

```
Deploying to http://localhost/ReportServer
Error rsServerConfigurationError : The report server has encountered a configuration error. 
Deploy complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

and when i go to this url `http://localhost/ReportServer`  in IE(Internet Explorer ) then it show me like this in browser 
[pic IE](http://i43.tinypic.com/a5pae.png)

where problem occurred and how i resolved this problem

i try so many times to deploy errors but in every time any error must come ..ughh :(

Comment: what about the other report? do they work fine? are the settings in the reporting services configuration manager set properly?

Comment: what is other report..i deploy report first time and even when i try so many times then probelm not solve..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see if SSRS will resolve 'localhost' correctly.  There are a few things to think about deploying to SSRS as well.

1. You need to be a role under the SSRS site that allows deployment.  You can try all day and if your 'Role Assignment' is not 'Publisher' or 'Content Manager' for your domain user/user or applicable group in a domain you will not be able to publish.
2. SSRS resolves to fully qualified paths and any breaks in names or leaving a report folder blank could potentially cause issues.  When you are in Business Intelligence Development Studio(BIDS in Visual Studio), your project's 'properties' must be configured correctly and for the correct version of SSRS you are deploying to.
3. Check the SSRS Config tool for what it shows the service to be at qualified.  Generally it is:

   ```
   http:// (servername)/ReportServer
   ```

   NOT

   ```
   http:// localhost/ReportServer
   ```

I wrote up a pretty thorough answer to this on another thread.

[How SSRS deployment works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105007/how-ssrs-deployment-works/18113853#18113853)

Comment: i read ur complete answer and also apply and when i go to report project properties and set target service url i,e http://(servername)/reportserver instead of localhost and when i deploy then it shows me login box who ask me enter username and password but i dont have password in sl server 2008 r2 and also in windows so what can i do...please help

Comment: You need PERMISSION to deploy, you need to grant it to yourself or have an admin give it to you.  It is in the link I gave 'How SSRS deployment works?'

Comment: how i grant it to may self ...and when i set a password in windows and then login then it show me blank page ..

Comment: You need to login as the admin on the server that has SSRS installed and grant permissions from there.  You should verify on the server you can see the page correctly first as well.  If you have done this and get a blank page it is dealing with either a firewall preventing the page or the user is not seeing the page correctly with a drawing issue probably from using Firefox or Chrome and not viewing it with Direct X as just as a guess.  My link 'How SSRS deployment works?' goes over the steps to check for deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make any changes to the reporting services config files?

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer

Is ReportManager working ok?
Have you another ReportServer that you can deploy to?

If it deploys elsewhere ok, I would re-install reporting services

Comment: no i can not make any changes in report server ..and this is first report server which i deploy and i also re-install 2 times reporting services... but still not works

Answer (score 0):

I have red that you have IIS and SSRS Server on the same machine. The standard port for both is 80, perhaps it would worth a try to change the port for SSRS to a different value. (Reporting Services Configuration Manager -> Web Service URL -> TCP Port and Report Manager URL -> Advanced -> Edit -> TCP Port)